# Can't get counter to work inside function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, dynamically-generated

I am trying to create the proverbial quiz in Javascript as my first 'from scratch' exercise. This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QpXen/4/), which has all the other code.

This is my question:

```
var allQuestions = [{
    "question": "Who was Luke's gunner in the battle at Hoth?",
    "choices": ["Dak", "Biggs", "Wedge", "fx-7"],
    "correctAnswer": 0
}];
```

Here in this function, I included the loop which should go over the radio buttons vs. the users selection. See below.

```
function answerFwd() {
    var answerOutput = " ";
    var itemAnswers = allQuestions;
    var answer = 0;
    var playerTally = 0;
    var playerFeedback = "";
    var playerMessage = document.getElementById("playerMessage");
```

Right now I am stuck with this; 
Matching the correct answer in the array, with what a user would select in the radio buttons and then dynamically displaying a score.

Right now, I can get the 0 to display, but no increment.

```
    var radioValue = $("input[type='radio'].radioButtons:checked").val();

    if (currentAnswer <= itemAnswers.length) {
        currentAnswer++;
    }
    createRadioButtonFromArray(itemAnswers[currentQuestion].choices);

    for(i = 0; i < radioValue.length; i++) {
      if(radioValue[i].checked) {
           if(radioValue[i].value == itemAnswers.correctAnswer) {
                playerTally++;
                break;
           }
      }
    }

    playerFeedback += "<h4>" + playerTally + "</h4> <br/>";
    playerMessage.innerHTML = playerFeedback;
}
```

I am not opposed to a solution with jQuery, but would prefer a vanilla JS alternative, just so I can really see what is going on!

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You have itemAnswers.correctAnswer  but I believe you need allQuestions[i].correctAnswer - and you already use jQuery which is not relevant to your actual problem as far as I can see

Comment: @ mplungjan Thanks for responding, but that didn't work. I get zero to propagate but it doesn't increase...

Comment: I see you copy to itemAnswers but you still need itemAnswers[i] - anyway, create a fiddle that shows the complete issue

Comment: Here's my fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/718BkQns/qLowcqe8/3/

Answer (score 0):

Before you progress to the next question, you can figure out if an answer is correct with

```
if (document.querySelectorAll("#responses input")[allQuestions[currentQuestion].correctAnswer].checked)
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Me! Hey I updated my fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/718BkQns/qLowcqe8/3/ but doesn't seem to work! Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually this is correct but hard to read and not shown in context.

Comment: I was in a hurry to leave when I wrote that code out so it's an ugly one liner. Use the version mplungjan wrote out. It's prettier.

Answer (score 0):

The complete solution is

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/53jnsnth/)

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll("#responses input");
var correct = allQuestions[currentAnswer].correctAnswer;

if (radios[correct].checked) {
  playerTally++;
  playerFeedback += "<h5>" + playerTally + "</h5> <br/>";
  playerMessage.innerHTML = playerFeedback;
}


if (currentAnswer <= itemAnswers.length) {
    currentAnswer++;
}
```

And now I look closely it is the same as Mr. Me's

Comment: Hmm, the code in the snippet above didn't work. Hey could you please repost the fiddle? Right now it's linking to some form and not my quiz...
Thanks

Comment: Updated answer. It is not complete since you really should work on the back or remove the back arrow

Comment: Thanks, but the fiddle doesn't work. Or I should say the code doesn't advance me beyond what I already had. But I really appreciated your help!

Comment: Either the fiddle works or it does not work. If it works, then why did it not bring you closer to a solution?

Comment: I had managed to get the counter/number to appear in the DOM/ on the page , but as you progress to the next question, it doesn't increment.

Perhaps I need to display a counter like so `0/20`, that way the user can ascertain their progress.